# Jackson NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, json, gradle, jackson

I am getting this error when I run this toy example from:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/16/jackson-examples-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

My gradle file has:

```
dependencies {
    classpath('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13')
}
```

Error:

> java -jar build/libs/pojo-test-0.1.0.jar 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerationException
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)

Changing my gradle as per suggestion to include core-asl still gives the same errors (see changes):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13')
        classpath('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13')
    }
}
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'JavaToJSONExample'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13')
    compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13')
}
```

Comment: This may not be the direct issue, but you're using an obsolete (version 1) version of Jackson; the latest is 2.6.1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with the old Jackson implementation, you need to also import jackson-core-asl:

```
  dependencies {
        classpath('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13')
        classpath('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13')
    }
```

Comment: See my edit to the question, I tried that but with no change to errors.

Comment: jackson-core-asl does contain the file you are looking for (see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerationException.java?av=f). Please try to rebuild the project to make your gradle changes effective.

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependency in graddle

```
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.1'
```

along with the mapper dependency.
Also, kindly upgrade the mapper version with

```
'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1'
```

Comment: No luck, compiles fine but I always get the same error as in the OP.